# AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: `select` failed ("badConnection")

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm getting the following error if I run any api end point where db operation is involved in sails.js (v 1.4.0). I'm using sails-mysql (v 1.0.1).
For your information, it is producing this error in aws ec2 ubuntu 18. My node version 13/14.
I'm not getting any error in my development environment.

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
     AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: `select` failed ("badConnection").  A connection either could not be obtained or there was an error using the connection.
    Additional data:
    
    {
      error: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN abmaster
          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)
          --------------------
          at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
          at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
          at PoolConnection.connect (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
          at Pool.getConnection (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
          at Object.getConnection (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/machinepack-mysql/lib/get-connection.js:78:25)
          at wrapper (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3282:19)
          at Deferred.parley.retry [as _handleExec] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1076:19)
          at Deferred.exec (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:286:10)
          at Deferred.switch (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1469:16)
          at spawnConnection (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails-mysql/helpers/private/connection/spawn-connection.js:29:10)
          at Object.spawnOrLeaseConnection (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails-mysql/helpers/private/connection/spawn-or-lease-connection.js:23:3)
          at Object.select (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails-mysql/helpers/select.js:122:24)
          at wrapper (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3282:19)
          at Deferred.parley.retry [as _handleExec] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1076:19)
          at Deferred.exec (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:286:10)
          at Deferred.switch (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1469:16)
          at Object.find (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:185:16)
          at _getPopulatedRecords (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/help-find.js:145:21)
          at helpFind (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/help-find.js:582:6)
          at _afterPotentiallyRunningBeforeLC (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:265:9)
          at _maybeRunBeforeLC (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:239:16)
          at Deferred._.extend._WLModel [as _handleExec] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:241:9)
          at Deferred.exec (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:286:10)
          at Object.findOneRecord (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/findOne.js:37:4)
          at /var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:248:46
          at routeTargetFnWrapper (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:395:9)
          at /var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:458:14
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
        errno: -3001,
        code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
        hostname: 'abmaster',
        fatal: true
      },
      meta: {
        host: 'test.anonderbazar.com',
        port: 3306,
        schema: true,
        adapter: 'sails-mysql',
        url: 'mysql://abmaster:duY$1L#8rwof@test.anonderbazar.com:3306/anonderbazaar',
        connectTimeout: 20000,
        identity: 'default'
      }
    }
        at Object.findOneRecord (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/findOne.js:36:4)
        at /var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:248:46
        at routeTargetFnWrapper (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:395:9)
        at /var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:458:14
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at /var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
        at param (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
        at param (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
        at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
        at next (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at next (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:127:14)
        at alwaysAllow (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:178:16)
        at routeTargetFnWrapper (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:395:9)
        at /var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:458:14
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at /var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
        at param (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
        at param (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
        at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
        at next (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at next (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:127:14)
        at Hook.expressMiddleware (/var/www/html/api/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/i18n/index.js:205:14)
```

Any kind of help from anyone will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, my problem was that the password of my user had an '@' and in the connection there was also one, change the password and solve the error